# Run multiple maven <execution> in parallel

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

In my project, I have multiple maven plugin executions to run test cases as below:

```
                 <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>abc<id>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <argLine>${argLine} -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m</argLine>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                      <id>def</id>
                      ...
                      ...
                      </executions>
                </executions>
```

I am a beginner in maven and test suites execution and I recently came across that test cases can be run in parallel in maven.

From documentation I got that **methods, classes, suites** can be run in parallel.
I wish to know if the above executions altogether can be run in parallel.

Thanks.